# How to retrieve paragraph alignment values with python-docx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to automate the formating of docx files using python-docx. I want to get the value of paragraphs alignment. My code works for most paragraphs, but there is a paragraph in a docx file I am testing that is aligned as "justify",  but I can't get this information with code.

```
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
a1 = paragraph.alignment
a2 = paragraph.style.paragraph_format.alignment
a3 = paragraph.style.base_style.paragraph_format.alignment
```

The code above works for most cases, but not for every case. Is there another place where this information could be stored?

In case someone wants to access the test file:
docx: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PG4eZGWvDG9shhAB7xPPkpjFjiO2W9PW/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108709886188812681637&rtpof=true&sd=true

zip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L1TOdLP_RNDxddUqpkDHPNT55NGT7MCZ/view?usp=sharing

The problem is at paragraph index = 11 (text = "O **Congresso Nacional** decreta:"). For this paragraph, a1, a2 and a3 are all equal "None", although the paragraph is formated visually as "justify".

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I will add here the solution, in case someone face the same problem. The alignment value can be stored in any of these places:

```
paragraph.alignment
paragraph.style.paragraph_format.alignment
paragraph.style.base_style.paragraph_format.alignment
paragraph.style.base_style.base_style.paragraph_format.alignment
paragraph.style.base_style.base_style.base_style.paragraph_format.alignment
```

In other words, a style can be inherited from another style. This inherence can be as long as one wants. So you should keep checking for the alignment value while paragraph.style.base_style is not None.

Comment: `zip` file requires extraction.  possible to post the plain `docx` file for a MRE.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, paragraph style is an *inheritance tree* of arbitrary depth (although perhaps unusual for it to be more than three levels deep). Actually it would be a *forest* because there can be multiple "trees", but each style is part of only one tree. A style with no base style is the "root" of a style inheritance tree.

To determine the *effective* value of a formatting attribute, the style tree is traversed upward from the assigned style. The first style node that defines that attribute determines its effective value. A formatting attribute applied directly to the paragraph "wins" over any style.

```py
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

alignment = effective_alignment(paragraph)

def effective_alignment(paragraph: Paragraph) -> WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH | None:
    alignment = paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment
    if alignment is not None:
        return alignment
    return effective_style_alignment(paragraph.style)

def effective_style_alignment(style: ParagraphStyle) -> WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH | None:
    """Recursively navigate up style hierarchy to find alignment."""
    alignment = style.paragraph_format.alignment
    if alignment is not None:
        return alignment
    base_style = style.base_style
    if base_style is None:
        return None
    return effective_style_alignment(base_style)
```

The recursive approach here avoids having to guess about how deep inheritance might happen to be in a given document.